# DataTables jQuery plugin nowrap for Ajax table

Tags: jquery, datatables

Can someone give me an example of how to add a nowrap="nowrap" to a column when all  information is generated on the fly for an ajax table?

```
$('#results').dataTable({
    "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
        $(nRow).attr('id', aData[0]);
        return nRow;
    },
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",  
    "bProcessing": true,
    "sAjaxSource": 'ajax/purchasers.php',
    "aaSorting": [[1,'asc']],                   
    "aoColumns": [                              
        { "bVisible": false },                      
        null,                                   
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null
    ]
});
```

I know this might be a long shot.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In case anyone is interested in the solution, you can use fnInitComplete to loop over the table after DataTables is done rendering it like so:

```
$('#results').dataTable({
    "fnInitComplete": function() {
        $('#results tbody tr').each(function(){
                $(this).find('td:eq(0)').attr('nowrap', 'nowrap');
        });
    },
    "sAjaxSource": 'ajax/purchasers.php'
});
```

Comment: Please see my answer for a better solution from a performance standpoint. You probably don't want to loop over the entire table while you can add a simple css class during initialization. Try both options with a large number of rows. If you are not dealing with large number of rows you are probably fine.

Comment: The solution is with CSS!

Answer (score 8):

It's better to achieve this through styling instead.

```
"aoColumns": [                              
    { "sClass": "my_class"},
```

in the stylesheet

```
    .my_class {
   white-space:nowrap;
 }
```

Comment: WHile using pagination and testing jeerose's method only the first page of the table gets the attributes assigned... so styling it using the aoColumns is a better choice.

Answer (score 2):

While it certainly will work to add a class and create a CSS entry for this it seems like using a hammer to pound in a screw.

Datatables already provides an easy way of doing this.

In your dataTable declaration add:

```
"fnRowCallback": function( nRow ) {
    if(nRow.cells[2]) nRow.cells[2].noWrap = true;  // column index starts with 0 and we check if cells[2] is null to be ultra safe
    return nRow;
},
```

Hope this helps

Comment: jeerose's post requires external (to datatables) javascript and Karthik's requires external (to datatables) css.  This should play nicely with anything dataTables is trying to do.