# Nowrap for dynamic jquery datatables from json

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I am trying to add nowrap for my jquery datatable without success.

Something like this (not working)

```
$.ajax( {
    "url": 'invokeHawkAgent.gsp',
    "success": function ( json ) {
        json.bDestroy = true;
        $('#tabs-1-contents').dataTable({'data':json,
            "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
                $('td', nRow).attr('nowrap','nowrap');
                return nRow;
             }
        });
    },
    "dataType": "json"
} );
```

Working (but without nowrap)

```
$.ajax( {
    "url": 'invokeHawkAgent.gsp',
    "success": function ( json ) {
        json.bDestroy = true;
        $('#tabs-1-contents').dataTable(json);
    },
    "dataType": "json"
} );
```

Any ideas how to add nowrap to this?

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you just set it from css?

Comment: Actually I would like to use jquery to add more characteristics to the table in the dataTable function. Setting nowrap is just a first step to do this.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270244/datatables-jquery-plugin-nowrap-for-ajax-table ? @user955732 http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/1365/nowrap-for-ajax-table/p1 discusses this problem and offers two solutions, try, and if it works you can post your own answer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Rafael Cichocki, but I don't think my post is a duplicate, 
in the referred discussion they use "sAjaxSource": 'ajax/purchasers.php' to populate the dataTable and I use the results from an ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, this is how I solved the problem:

JSON

```
{
    "aaData":[
    { 
        "0": "2010-07-27 10:43:08", 
        "1" :  "...", 
        "2" : "...", 
        "3" : "...", 
        "4" : "...", 
        "5" : "...", 
        "6" : "...", 
        "7" : "...",
        "DT_RowId": "row",
        "DT_RowClass": "gradeC"
    },
    { 
        "0": "2010-07-27 10:43:08", 
        "1" :  "...", 
        "2" : "...", 
        "3" : "...", 
        "4" : "...", 
        "5" : "...", 
        "6" : "...", 
        "7" : "...",
        "DT_RowId": "row",
        "DT_RowClass": "gradeC"
    }
    ] ,
     "aaSorting": [
      [ 1, "desc" ]
     ],
     "aoColumns": [
       { "sTitle": "Title1" },
       { "sTitle": "Title2" },
       { "sTitle": "Title3" },
       { "sTitle": "Title4" },
       { "sTitle": "Title5" },
       { "sTitle": "Title6" },
       { "sTitle": "Title7" },
       { "sTitle": "Title8" }
     ]
}
```

jQuery:

```
$.ajax( {
    "url": 'invokeHawkAgent.gsp',
    "success": function ( json ) {
        json.bDestroy = true;
        $('#tabs-1-contents').dataTable({
            "aaData": json.aaData,
            "aoColumns": json.aoColumns,
            "sScrollX": "100%",
            "sScrollXInner": "110%",
            "bScrollCollapse": true,
            "sScrollY": "500px",
            "bPaginate": true,
            "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
                $('td', nRow).attr('nowrap','nowrap');
                return nRow;
                }
            });
        },
    "dataType": "json"
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bootstrap, simply add class `text-nowrap` in your title classes.

```
{
 "title": "My Title",
 "data": "My Data",
 "className": "text-center nosort text-nowrap"
}
```

It works fine for me.